# How to get attributes from foreignkey model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have three models, item, variation and item_variations. The item has a foreignkey relation with variation, which in turn have a foreignkey relation with ItemVariation model. My question is, how do I access the attributes of Item variation to get hold of dynamic data by using the model Item. But I'm not being able to do so. Can anyone please help me with this?

My models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.FloatField()

class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) # size, color

class ItemVariation(models.Model):
    variation  = models.ForeignKey(Variation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50) # small, medium large etc
```

My admin.py:

```
class ItemVariationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['variation',
                    'value']

    list_filter = ['variation', 'variation__item']
    search_fields = ['value']


class ItemVariationInLineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ItemVariation
    extra = 1


class VariationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['item',
                    'name']
    list_filter = ['item']
    search_fields = ['name']
    inlines = [ItemVariationInLineAdmin]


admin.site.register(ItemVariation, ItemVariationAdmin)
admin.site.register(Variation, VariationAdmin)
```

My views.py:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'products/product.html'
```

My product.html:

```
<h1 class="product-title">{{ item.title }}</h1>
                  <a href="#">
                    <span class="badge purple mr-1">{{ object.get_category_display }}</span>
                  </a> 
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{{ object.get_add_to_cart_url }}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if object.itemvariation_set.all %}

                      <h5>{{ object.itemvariation_set.all }}</h5>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="action">
                      <button class="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: It looks like the `Variation` has an fk to `Item`, not the opposite way.

Comment: It also looks rather odd, an item can have multiple `variations` and a variation` can have multiple `itemvariation`s?

Comment: Variations are the size, color etc.
and item_variations are the values of those
edit: my admin

Comment: Variations aside. You should query the result set in the view using select_related. To do this you need to make a custom view so you can pass in additional context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way you can display item variation set

```
{% for var in object.variation_set.all %}
 <h5>{{ var.name }}</h5>
{% for item in var.itemvariation_set.all %}
 <h5>{{ item.value }}</h5>
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy

Comment: okay man, if it is answered you, don't forget to mark as answer :)

Comment: Yea why not, I wanted to mark it as answered earlier, but it said to wait for two mins